# Using bash variable names as match replacement in perl regex substitution command line

Tags: regex, bash, shell, perl, command-line

I'm trying to replace substrings delimited by characters in a string by the values of their matching bash variables in shell.

So far, I've tried this without any success:

```
varone="noob"
vartwo="trivial"
echo "my {varone} and {vartwo} question" | perl -pe 's|(.*){(\w+)}(.*)|${1}'$(echo "${'${2}'}")'${3}|g'
```

But I get:

```
bash: ${'${2}'}: bad substitution
```

Any idea on how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't generate Perl code from the shell! [It isn't easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13354418/589924).

Instead of generating code, pass the values to the script. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53529756/589924) shows a couple of ways you can pass values to a Perl one-liner. Exporting the variables you want to interpolate is the simplest here.

```sh
export varone="noob"
export vartwo="trivial"
echo "my {varone} and {vartwo} question" |
   perl -pe's/\{(\w+)\}/$ENV{$1}/g'
```

It also means you can interpolate other variables like `PATH`. If that's no good, you'll have to somehow check if the variable name is legal.

```sh
export varone="noob"
export vartwo="trivial"
echo "my {varone} and {vartwo} question" |
   perl -pe's/\{(varone|vartwo)\}/$ENV{$1}/g'
```

Comment: That's it, I appreciate the perl solution without any external storage as well, thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 5):

Your main problem here is that you need to use `export` in order for your variables to be seen in your subprocesses (like the `perl` process).

```
export varone="noob"
export vartwo="trivial"
echo "my {varone} and {vartwo} question" | perl -pe '...'
```

You also need to know that shell variables are accessed inside a Perl program using the `%ENV` hash.

So your code can be simplified to:

```
export varone="noob"
export vartwo="trivial"
echo "my {varone} and {vartwo} question" | perl -pe 's|\{(\w+)}|$ENV{$1}|g'
```

You might consider adding an option to check for unknown variables.

```
export varone="noob"
export vartwo="trivial"
echo "my {varone} and {vartwo} question {varxxx}" | perl -pe 's|\{(\w+)}|$ENV{$1}//"UNKNOWN"|g'
```

But I'd recommend looking at a [proper templating engine](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template) for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `export` to access bash variables in Perl scripts:

Try this:

```
export varone="noob"
export vartwo="trivial"
echo "my {varone} and {vartwo} question" | perl -pe 's|(.*){(\w+)}(.*){(\w+)}(.*)|${1}${ENV{$2}}${3}${ENV{$4}}${5}|g'
```

**Example**

```
echo "my {varone} and {vartwo} question" | perl -pe 's|(.*){(\w+)}(.*){(\w+)}(.*)|${1}${ENV{$2}}${3}${ENV{$4}}${5}|g'
my noob and trivial question
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

```
echo "my {varone} and {vartwo} question" | \
     perl -wpE 'BEGIN{ %h = @ARGV;@ARGV=() } s|{(\w+)\}|$h{$1}|g' \
     "varone" "$varone" "vartwo" "$vartwo"
```

**Output**:

```
my noob and trivial question
```

Comment: -E is not forward compatible. It shouldn't be used except for single-use scripts.