# Bash, is there a way to get the same function as double quoting a variable without using double quotes

Tags: bash

I would like to get the same effect as `vim "$p"`, but without using double quotes, where `$p` is a path with special characters and spaces.

e.g. something a desirable `DOUBLE_QUOTE` function: `vim $(DOUBLE_QUOTE $p)`

After lots of reasearch I tried:

- `vim $(echo ${p@Q})`

...all with no success (I get quotes showing up in the path)

Background: The reason is the string is passed between a few window batch scrips, and programs, and I have spent the weekend trying to escape the double quotes through multiple layers with no success.

Comment: You could make a symlink called `it` with `ln - s "weird thing with spaces" it` and then do `vim it`

Comment: What do you do with the script? Why exactly the double quotes don't meet your needs?

Comment: Why not use double quote? If you call ```myScript.sh "a b c"```, inside the sccript the variable ```$1``` has the value without quotes. Then you can pass it on to the next script by inside the ```nextScript.sh "$1"```.

Comment: Ask about your *actual* problem, not what you think is the solution to that problem.

Comment: If one of the special characters is `#` you will have a tough time without using double-quote.

Comment: @stark, That's not a problem. It's whitespace that consists of anything but a single space that's the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing

```sh
IFS=
```

You can use

```sh
vim $p
```

Otherwise, no.

---

With the default value of `IFS`, `bash` will split the value of `$p` on sequences of spaces, tabs and/or linefeeds. That will make it impossible to send `a␠␠b` (two spaces in the middle) to `DOUBLE_QUOTE`, and `DOUBLE_QUOTE` would be unable to distinguish `a␠b` (spaces in the middle) from `a␉b` (tab in the middle).

Furthermore, the value returned by `DOUBLE_QUOTE` would also be subject to this splitting.

As such,

```sh
vim $( DOUBLE_QUOTE $p )
```

would have to be

```sh
vim "$( DOUBLE_QUOTE "$p" )"
```

to work with the default value of `IFS`.

---

If, on the other hand, you are trying to generate shell commands, you can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13354247/589924)'s answers for help.

For example,

```sh
printf '%s\n' "$( quote vim "$p" )"
```

outputs

```
'vim' 'a  b'
```

given

```sh
p='a  b'
```

and

```sh
# quote() - Creates a shell literal
# Usage:  printf '%s\n' "$( quote "..." "..." "..." )"
quote() {
    local prefix=''
    local p
    for p in "$@" ; do
        printf "$prefix"\'
        printf %s "$p" | sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g"
        printf \'
        prefix=' '
    done
}
```

Comment: IFS= did the trick, thank you so much!!! I also eventually figured out to get a " to appear in the final script, I needed to send \\"^""    but your way is much cleaner.