# Filter both stderr and stdout, but keep them on stderr and stdout in a /bin/sh compatible way

Tags: sh, exec, file-descriptor

This question resembles [Pipe only STDERR through a filter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3618078/363028), but I want both STDOUT and STDERR and I do not want output merged.

I want:

```
STDOUT ── [ filter ] ────> STDOUT
                       
STDERR ── [ filter ] ────> STDERR
```

And I want to keep $?. If `myprogram` is a function, I want it to be able to change the environment.

In Bash I can do:

```
myprogram() {
    echo stdout;
    echo stderr >&2;
    myvar=this_value
    (exit 3)
}

myfilter() {
    perl -pe "s/^/$@ /"
    echo filter "$@" stderr >&2
}

{ myprogram || foo=$?.$myvar; } 2> >(myfilter errfilter >&2) > >(myfilter outfilter)
wait
echo error=$foo
echo Done
```

This works on a read-only file system.

I want to do the same in /bin/sh. But there is no `>(cmd)` construct.

In /bin/sh I can do:

```
{ myprogram || foo=$?.$myvar; } >/tmp/tmpout 2>/tmp/tmperr
myfilter errfilter </tmp/tmperr >&2
myfilter outfilter </tmp/tmpout >&1
echo error=$foo
echo Done
```

(This will fail if stdout/stderr from `myprogram` is bigger than the disk, and will not work on a read-only file system).

Or:

```
mkfifo /tmp/fifoout
mkfifo /tmp/fifoerr
myfilter errfilter </tmp/fifoerr >&2 &
myfilter outfilter </tmp/fifoout >&1 &
{ myprogram || foo=$?.$myvar; } >/tmp/fifoout 2>/tmp/fifoerr
wait
echo error=$foo
echo Done
```

(This will fail if `/tmp` is read-only).

Can it be done in /bin/sh without using temporary files or named pipes?

I am thinking whether this can be done with some `exec 2>&- 3>&1` magic.

This does not work, but I have the feeling it could work given the correct `exec` magic:

```
exec 3>&1 4>&2
myfilter outfilter <&3 >&1 &
myfilter errfilter <&4 >&2 &
{ myprogram || foo=$?.$myvar; } 1>&3 2>&4
wait
echo error=$foo
echo Done
```

Answer (score 2):

Working on Ole Tange's attempt at a solution,

```bash
exec 3>&1                    # fd 3 = Original fd 1.
status="$(             # )"  # Syntax highlighting hack.
   exec 4>&1                 # fd 4 = Pipe to backticks (and thus to `$status`).
   {
      exec 5>&1              # fd 5 = Pipe to `filter out`.
      {
         program 2>&1 >&5    # Send to `filter out`.
         printf %s "$?" >&4  # Send to backticks (and thus to `$status`).
      } | filter err >&2
      exec 5>&-
   } | filter out >&3        # Send to original fd 1.
   exec 4>&-
)"                     # "   # Syntax highlighting hack.
exec 3>&-
( exit "$status" )           # Set `$?`.
```

Sample program and filter for testing:

```bash
program() { perl -e'print "a\nb\n"; warn "c\nd\n"; exit 42'; }

filter() { perl -spe'$_="$f $_"' -- -f="$1"; }
```

Comment: If I wanted to be cute, I'd replace `program 2>&1 >&5` with `exec 6>&1; program >&5 2>&6; exec 6>&-`, fd 6 being the pipe to `filter err`.

Comment: Can you get any changes to the enviroment, too (`$myvar` set in `myprogram`).

Comment: `exit 42`, beautiful!

Comment: Replace `printf %s "$?"` with something serializing the vars (e.g. by generating shell code that would recreate them), then recompose them at the end (e.g. by evaluating that shell code).

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13354247/589924) will help you generate that code.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested in detail, but it seems to work:

```
{
    exec 3>&1 
    myprogram 11 2>&1 >&3 | myfilter ferr >&2
    exec 3>&-
} | myfilter fout
```

However, it does not keep $? from `myprogram`.

Comment: I suppose with one more file descriptor you could `echo $? >&4` and capture it after the pipeline; but figuring out how exactly to do that makes my head hurt.