# How can I look up a variable by name with #!/bin/sh (POSIX sh)?

Tags: linux, sh

```
f1="filename1";
i=1;
c=f$i
echo $c
```

What shell command should I use so that `echo $c` returns "filename1" as the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval` to "nest" variable substitutions.

```
f1="filename1";
i=1;
eval c=\${f$i}
echo $c
```

Comment: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/shell.xml states use should avoid eval. This example is safe, but do not use eval with user-input.

Comment: Unless you need to support this in POSIX `sh`, use your shell's syntax for indirect parameter expansion where possible.

Comment: @WalterA It's fine to use `eval` with user input, assuming it's properly quoted. [Here's a function to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52538533/5353461)

Comment: @TomHale Nice function in the link. However, that function won't work in POSIX /bin/sh (OP asks for `#!/bin/sh (POSIX sh)`).

Comment: Granted, that function is `{ba,z}sh` code. You could [POSIXify the `printf %q`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29824428/5353461) with `printf '%s\n' "$1" | sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g; 1 s/^/'/; $ s/$/'/"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use variable indirection.

```
#!/bin/bash
f1="filename1";
i=1;
c=f$i
echo ${!c}
```

It works in bash ( GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release ). I have not tried in other shells.

Comment: Works in bash 4.3.30 and sh 4.3 too, although not in zsh 5.0.7.

Comment: @jdehesa Note that it only works in `sh` because `/bin/sh` is a link to `bash` on your machine. `${!var}` is a `bash` extension and not available in POSIX shell. Incidentally, the `zsh` equivalent is `${(P)c}`.

Answer (score 0):

### Reusable function

```
# Expand the variable named by $1 into its value. Works in both {ba,z}sh
# eg: a=HOME $(var_expand $a) == /home/me
var_expand() {
  if [ -z "${1-}" ] || [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    printf 'var_expand: expected one argument\n' >&2;
    return 1;
  fi
  eval printf '%s' "\"\${$1?}\""
}
```

It warns when given:

- Null input
- More than one argument
- A variable name which isn't set