# Use string as bash variable name in alternative value expansion

Tags: bash, variable-expansion, variable-substitution

How can I use the value of one variable as the name of another variable in an alternative value expansion [(`${var+alt}`)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) in bash?

I would think that

```
#!/bin/bash
cat='dog'
varname='cat'
if [ -z ${`echo "${varname}"`+x} ]; then
    echo 'is null'
fi
```

should be roughly equivalent to

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z ${dog+x} ]; then
    echo 'is null'
fi
```

but when I try to do this, I get

```
${`echo "${cat}"`+x}: bad substitution
```

I guess part of the problem is that the subshell doing the command substitution doesn't know about `$varname` anymore? Do I need to export that variable?

My reason for doing this is that I learned from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13864829/2407870) how to check if a variable is null, and I'm trying to encapsulate that check in a function called `is_null`, like this:

```
function is_null {
    if [ $# != 1 ]; then
        echo "Error: is_null takes one argument"
        exit
    fi
    # note: ${1+x} will be null if $1 is null, but "x" if $1 is not null
    if [ -z ${`echo "${1}"`+x} ]; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

if is_null 'some_flag'; then
    echo 'Missing some_flag'
    echo $usage
    exit
fi
```

Comment: I think you need this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337826/in-linux-shell-script-how-can-i-recall-value-of-variable/26337979#26337979

Comment: @Ashwani Thank you, that's just what I needed. I changed my if statement to `if [ -z ${!1+x} ]; then ...`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem.

If I got, what you need is `eval` command.

```
$ cat='dog'

$ varname='cat'

$ echo ${varname}

cat

$ eval echo \$${varname}

dog
```

Comment: What he was looking for was **indirection**, while that can be accomplished with `eval`, the use of `eval` is frowned upon in such circumstances.

Comment: @Davison I appreciate your answer - `eval` can do the job, but as David said, I was trying to avoid the use of that sledgehammer in favor of a more precise tool. I forgot to mark my question as duplicate to the link posted above.