# Print variables with number of iteration index in dash

Tags: sh, dash-shell

I work in dash and I would like to know if there is any method to print variable with index of number of iteration.

**CODE :**

```
var1="a"
var2="b"
var3="c"

tmp=0
while [ $tmp -lt 4 ]
do
    # this is how i imagine it 
    echo $('var'$tmp)  #output should be value of var$tmp
    tmp=$((tmp+1))
done
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you have a `bash` tag on a question about dash?

Comment: BTW, what you're asking for is called "indirect expansion".

Comment: Something like this?  `eval "$('var'$tmp)"` ?

Comment: the `$()` is wrong there. But yes, you need to use `eval` (and run the associated security risks) to get indirect expansion in dash.

Comment: BTW, you're missing quoting -- the test really should be `[ "$tmp" -lt 4 ]`, as http://shellcheck.net/ will point out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I look up a variable by name with #!/bin/sh (POSIX sh)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337826/in-linux-shell-script-how-can-i-recall-value-of-variable)

Comment: (argh -- I missed the "bash" in the title. `#!/bin/sh` **is not bash**, and questions about it should not be tagged or titled as bash questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In POSIX sh, you need to use `eval` to perform indirect expansion:

```
eval "result=\$var$tmp"
```

Note that there are much better ways to do this in ksh, bash or other shells; see [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) for a comprehensive discussion of both indirect expansion and indirect assignment spanning all these shells.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Using `eval` like below

```
eval "echo \"\$var${tmp}\""
# The \ escapes the $ to make it a literal dollar sign
```

should do it without using a third variable.

<sup>**Note:** [@Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy)'s [[ comment ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43051857/print-variables-with-number-of-iteration-index-in-dash/43052125?noredirect=1#comment73189194_43052125) below is taken into consideration in the edit.</sup>

Comment: I'm pretty staunchly against passing `eval` more than one argument -- like `ssh`, it just concatenates those arguments with whitespace to form a single string. Better to `eval "echo \"\$var${tmp}\""` -- that way we're actually *explicit* about what's going on, and won't have surprising events when your command is more involved than `echo`.

Comment: (consider `eval printf '%s\n' "hello world"`, compared to `eval 'printf "%s\n" "hello world"'`, for a case-in-point example of why passing `eval` multiple arguments leads to confusion).