# Quoted printing of shell variables

Tags: bash, shell, variables, printing, escaping

I would like to print the contents of a variable in such a way, that the printed output could be pasted directly into a shell to get the original content of the variable.

This is trivial if the content doesn't contain any special characters, esp no quotes. e.g.

```
$ x=foo
$ echo x=${x}
x=foo
```

In the above example i can take the output (`x=foo` and paste it into a new terminal to assign `foo` to `x`).

If the variable content contains spaces, things get a bit trickier, but it's still easy:

```
$ x="foo bar"
$ echo x=\"${x}\"
x="foo bar"
```

Now trouble starts, if the variable is allowed to contain any character, e.g.:

```
$ x=foo\"bar\'baz
$echo ${x}
foo"bar'baz
$ echo x=\"${x}\"
x="foo"bar'baz"
$ x="foo"bar'baz"
>
```

(and the terminal hangs, waiting for me to close the unbalanced `"`)

What I would have expected was an output like the following:

```
x=foo\"bar\'baz
```

How would I do that, preferably POSIX compliant (but if it cannot be helped, bash only)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `declare -p`:

```
x=foo\"bar\'baz
declare -p x
```

```
declare -- x="foo\"bar'baz"
```

Even with an array:

```
arr=(a 'foo' 'foo bar' 123)
declare -p arr
```

```
declare -a arr='([0]="a" [1]="foo" [2]="foo bar" [3]="123")'
```

The `-p` option will display the attributes and values of each variable name that can be used to directly set the variable again.

---

As per comment, doing this in POSIX without help of `declare -p` would be:

```
set | grep '^x='
```

Comment: nice. obviously this is `bash` only (which is ok, as mentioned in the question). but is there a POSIX compliant sulotion as well?

Comment: Doing this in POSIX without help of `declare -p` would be probably `set | grep '^var='`

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `printf` command with its [`%q` flag](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf) it supports to print the associated argument shell-quoted

```
x=foo\"bar\'baz

printf 'x=%q' "$x"
x=foo\"bar\'baz
```

Again though `%q` is *not* a POSIX extension but added to most recent versions of `bash` shell. If this is what you where looking for look up this to see [POSIX `sh` equivalent for Bash's `printf %q`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12162010/5291015)